# How can I make a multiple required select option in html5?

Tags: html

How can I make a multiple required select option in html5? The user must select at least 2 options.

```
<select name='type' required multiple='multiple'>
    <option>...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work and doesn't check if there are more then one selected.

Comment: you have to use a javascript for that

Comment: thanks, i'll try it. I hoped it could be done without js.

Comment: I believe that it is not possible yet using only HTML5

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="choice" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

var optionsToSelect = ['One','two', 'three'];
var select = document.getElementById( 'choice' );

for ( var i = 0, l = select.options.length, o; i < l; i++ )
{
  o = select.options[i];
  if ( optionsToSelect.indexOf( o.text ) <= 1 )
  {
    alert('Plz select at least 2 options')

  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is wrong. What it does is alert if one of the texts of the html select is in optionsToSelect  at  index <= 1 (which is ALWAYS the case).

Answer (score -1):

A bit late but for other users that came long internet search.
You can do that using HTML5 but be sure you are not disabling the default behavior.

```
$("#mybtnId").click(function() {

  var isValid = $("#MyForm")[0].checkValidity();
  if(false === isValid){
    //allow the browser's default submit event behavior 
    return true;
  }
  event.preventDefault();  <-- disable default behavior after check validation

  //...
});
```